# The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing in django

Tags: python, django

I was trying to do a system that will delete an item from our cart .so I made a url and I pass the slug of the item into it to delete it from the Cart . bit there is a problem .

can you help please?

views.py

```
def remove_cart(request , slug):
url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
ca = product.objects.filter(slug = slug)
Cart.objects.filter(produ = ca).delete()
return redirect(url)
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'cart'

urlpatterns = [
path('' , views.cart_detail , name='cart_deatil'),
re_path(r'^add/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$' , views.add_cart , name='add_cart'),
re_path(r'^remove/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$' , views.remove_cart , name='remove_cart')
]
```

models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
produ = models.ForeignKey(product , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class CartForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = Cart
     fields = ['quantity']
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: the problem is the error in the title

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it. There was `.objects.fillter` in the `views.py` and when I changed it to `get`, then it worked!

Comment: Normally it will not only remove the product from the cart of the user, but from the carts of *all* users.